# Get default date format in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, date, datetime

For a wordpress plugin I need the default date format set in options->general. I need the format string (like 'Y-m-d H:i:s') for usage in the Carbon library. In the documentation I didn't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Date and time formats are stored separately as options.

Use `get_option()` to retrieve the value.

E.g.

```
$date_format = get_option( 'date_format' ); // e.g. "F j, Y"
$time_format = get_option( 'time_format' ); // e.g. "H:i:s"
```